# How to create a column and fill in values based on condition(ifelse) in pydatatable data frame?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have created a datatable frame as follows,

```
DT_EX = dt.Frame({'income':[1000,2000,3000,2500,5000]})
```

Here i would like to add a new column(profit_or_loss) to it on a specific condition as

If the income is greater than 2500 a value 'Profit' should be filled in the newly created column or else another value 'Loss' should be in.

Here is another case:

```
DT_EX_1 = dt.Frame( {'domestic_income':[4500,2500,1500,4000], 'internationaL_income':[2000,5000,1000,4500]})
```

In a new column(profit_loss), if this condition is met domestic_income>international_income its value should be filled in as 'Profit' or else 'Loss'

**Note:** It's a kind of fifelse functionality in R datatable.

Comment: As per guildelines given by h2o pydatatable team this feature will be added in next release 0.11

Comment: feature request https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/2411 - included in 0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not yet implemented, and it's under feature request